# Concatenating dataframes along the column axis with identical indexes containing duplicate indices

Tags: python, pandas

Is it expected behaviour that no error is raised when concatenating dataframes with identical indexes which contain duplicate indices? Can I rely on this?

For example,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_A = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 0],
...                     data=[0, 1],
...                     columns=['A'])
>>> df_A
   A
0  0
0  1
>>> df_B = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 0],
...                     data=[2, 3],
...                     columns=['B'])
>>> df_B
   B
0  2
0  3

>>> pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis='columns')
   A  B
0  0  2
0  1  3
```

Comment: Does my reply answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I had already identified the behaviour you summarised. My question is more about whether this behaviour is by design and documented? I wasn't able to predict it from the documentation. Or are there any deeper principles that would have allowed me to predict this behaviour? I am hesitant to rely on this behaviour if it is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.concat` is clever enough to correctly align the indices in that case.

However, if there is a different number of duplicated indices between the two DataFrames, it will complain, e.g.

```
>>> df_A = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 0, 0],
                        data=[0, 1, 4],
                        columns=['A'])

>>> df_A 

   A
0  0
0  1
0  4

>>> df_B = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 0],
                        data=[2, 3],
                        columns=['B'])

>>> df_B

   B
0  2
0  3

>>> pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis='columns')
```

raises

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

The same happens if both have the same number of duplicated indices, but the order of the rows is slightly different, e.g.

```
>>> df_A = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 0],
                        data=[0, 1, 4],
                        columns=['A'])
>>> df_A

   A
0  0
1  1
0  4

>>> df_B = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 0, 1],
                        data=[2, 3, 5],
                        columns=['B'])
>>> df_B

   B
0  2
0  3
1  5

>>> pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis='columns')
```

raises

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects